# All icons pixelated on startup

Tags: boot

Icons pixelated and line through top task bar. nothing functions, can't even  open drop down to do shutdown. have hard shutdown and rebooted several times ?
But loads thumb nails/files on desktop just fine?

Thanks
Terry

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Unity, you could restart it by going to a virtual terminal (`Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F1`), logging in with username and password, then typing `unity`.

Comment: That got me a reboot, but unfortunately Back to the same pixelated desktop icons and menu bar. It now cycles back to the User/ password screen all by it.s self and no longer waits for me to try and open something.

Comment: @TerryRoss What do you mean by it cycles back to the login screen?

Comment: I guess another way to put it, is that it crashes back to the log in screen.

Comment: before finishing to load files or fillout the pixelated icons, it goes black and returns to the log in screen.